# Could a gene transplant make somebody magical in the Harry Potter world?

Tags: harry-potter, magic, magical-theory

Some magical abilities are determined by genes rather than by practice and knowledge.

For example, Parseltongue is granted simply by having the right genes, not by learning it. (Harry Potter knew Parseltongue because of his connection to Voldemort, and he lost the ability after Voldemort's connection to him was destroyed.)

> Knowing Parseltongue isn’t quite the same as learning Spanish. Firstly,
>   you don’t so much learn it, as just innately know it. The language is
>   incredibly rare, as Harry is told countless times. The only place it
>   isn’t rare, is within the **bloodline** of Salazar Slytherin himself – and
>   as such, **is usually hereditary**.

The author herself as said that magical abilities are based on genetics.

> Rowling: "Muggle-borns will have a witch or wizard somewhere on their
>   **family tree**, in some cases many, many generations back. The **gene**
>   resurfaces in some unexpected places."

Could a Muggle get a gene transplant at a young age and as the gene expressed itself as the child grew up, the person would become magical?

Note: The quotes above come [from Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/FanTheories/comments/5eg6dd/harry_potter_how_dumbledore_can_understand/).

Comment: Voldemort's soul latched on to Harry - his Parseltongue ability had nothing to do with genetics, unless you're arguing souls are genetic in nature (which has profound implications for metaphysics, but let's ignore that for now).

Comment: Where do you go to get a gene transplant?

Comment: Related: [Where did the “Magic Blood” of the Harry Potter Universe Originate From?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/18783/21267) and [How do muggles and wizards differ physiologically?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/146089/21267) and [How do Muggle-borns end up with magical ability?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/3345/21267)

Comment: Possible duplicate? [What evidence supports the idea that Voldemort (or others) could use magic to develop witches/wizards with genetically engineered/enhanced abilities?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/130022/51379)

Comment: @Blackwood You can get your own gene splicing kit by ordering a crispr-cas9 kit.

Comment: I think there was a similar question about magical blood transfusion... or maybe it was about midichlorians?

Comment: @AkshatMahajan I already know how Harry Potter got his Parseltongue abilities. Not sure why you mention any genetic component.

Comment: @RichS Your second paragraph explicitly cites Harry's Parseltongue ability in the same context of having the right genes. I presumed you meant it as an example

Comment: @AkshatMahajan I think you misread that paragraph. It says Harry could speak the language because of his **connection** to Voldemort. i.e. - The part of Voldemort's soul lodged inside Harry. When that piece of his soul was destroyed near the end of the 7th book, Harry could no longer speak Parseltongue. That paragraph does not say he got it because of a genetic connection.

Answer (score 3):

### We don't know

There is nothing in the source material, not the books nor the films nor Pottermore that gives any clue what the effects of such a transplant would be.

### Magic is *magic*

> "Oh dear, maths."
> —[JKR](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2004/0304-wbd.htm)

As evidenced by the quote, maths aren't JKR's strong point. I think it's not unreasonable to extend that to other sciences, such as biology. Much of her system of "magical blood" was drawn in an analogy to the Nazi's ideas of blood purity, even more than she had expected:

> #### Section: F.A.Q.
>
> #### Why are some people in the wizarding world (e.g., Harry) called 'half-blood' even though both their parents were magical?
>
> The expressions 'pure-blood', 'half-blood' and 'Muggle-born' have been coined by people to whom these distinctions matter, and express their originators' prejudices. As far as somebody like Lucius Malfoy is concerned, for instance, a Muggle-born is as 'bad' as a Muggle. Therefore Harry would be considered only 'half' wizard, because of his mother's grandparents.
>
> If you think this is far-fetched, look at some of the real charts the Nazis used to show what constituted 'Aryan' or 'Jewish' blood. **I saw one in the Holocaust Museum in Washington when I had already devised the 'pure-blood', 'half-blood' and 'Muggle-born' definitions, and was chilled to see that the Nazis used precisely the same warped logic as the Death Eaters. A single Jewish grandparent 'polluted' the blood, according to their propaganda.**
>
> —JKR, in [the FAQ on her old website](https://web.archive.org/web/20100416022559/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/faq_view.cfm?id=58) (emphasis mine)

Neither JKR's ideas of magic blood nor the (partial) inspiration for it were scientifically sound ideas. Most of her ideas about magic are, well, *magic*. As with many other ideas in *Harry Potter*, they just serve the narrative without having been developed beyond that. Many of the [harry-potter](/questions/tagged/harry-potter) questions on this Stack unearth the inconsistencies and contradictions that follow from that position.

Should there ever be a story in the *Harry Potter* universe that features a gene transplant, it will grant the receiver of the transplant as much magic as the story demands.

Until that story is written, no-one knows.

Comment: You won me over with the math quote.

Comment: @TerribleFan _"You had me at 'maths'"_?

Comment: @RichS anything else I could add to make this answer acceptable?

Comment: "JKR: *Okay, so Hermione is one of Harry's two best friends, and her parents are normal and normal people -- non-magic people are called Muggles in the book as you all know -- and because magic can just happen, you don't have to have a witch or a wizard as a parent, it can just come out of nowhere, like a genetic abnormality.*"